# Getting a substring from a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that attributes the value in a cell adjacently to other values in the sheet. The value in the cell is **"Nat Rep feasibility check for United States - Details by Region"**, in which the country variates - it can be "Australia";"Argentina" etc. I need to extract that country and put it next to the values in cause:

```
Sub RowInt()
    Dim rng As Range
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select
        Cells.Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
        Range("A7").Value = "Channel"
        Range("B7").Value = "Country"
        mystring = Cells(1, 3).Value
        NumRows = Range("C8", Range("C8").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To NumRows - 1
            Cells(j + 7, 2).Value = Replace(mystring, "Nat Rep feasibility check for", "")
            Cells(j + 7, 1).Value = Range("C2").Value
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I managed to get **"Nat Rep feasibility check for"** out of the way but i still need to get the rest of the string, can you help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the `vba` necessity here? Seems to be something that you can do with formula - if you provide example of data.

Comment: If there is always a `-` after the country name, that could be used as a marker.

Comment: There are multiple sheets and at the end i have to get them congregated in a single sheet, this is just preparing them for later use.

Comment: Yes there's always a "-" after the country name, I tried with Left after the first string removal but it returns to the original string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about removing both fixed parts of the string - as you were already doing in one case:

```
 Cells(j + 7, 2).Value = Replace(Replace(mystring, "Nat Rep feasibility check for ", ""), " - Details by Region", "")
```

Comment: If `MyString` = "Nat Rep feasibility check for USA - Details by Region" then the above would output "USA"

Comment: What produces "FALSE"? A replace can't produce FALSE unless it started with FALSE in it. Step through (`F8`) the procedure to monitor what's happening line-by-line.

Comment: @CLR im encountering an interesting error... when i copy yours it does not do the first replace until i copy and paste the "Nat Rep..." phrase from the original question...

Comment: manually typing the phrase "Nat Rep feasibility check for " will not work  - I have to copy and paste the exact string from the initial question even though the strings are (as far as i can tell) identical

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by this formula:

```
=MID(F8,LEN("Nat Rep feasibility check for ")+1,LEN(F8)-LEN("Nat Rep feasibility check for ")-LEN("Details by Region")-2)
```

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Clear and simple.

Comment: Sometimes I just can't understand why going for crazy solutions, keep it simple :)

Comment: Because this doesn't remove the "- Details By Region" from the end. You're only deleting the part OP has already successfully removed with `Replace`.

Comment: Sorry @MoondogsMaDawg, Haven't seen that. just use this one instead:
=MID(F8,LEN("Nat Rep feasibility check for ")+1,LEN(F8)-LEN("Nat Rep feasibility check for ")-LEN("Details by Region")-2)

Comment: A different version is mid(f8,find((“for “,f8,1)+4,len(f8)-find(“- D”,f8,1)+2)

Answer (score 0):

Use Split

**Example test sub**

```
Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print Split(Split("Nat Rep feasibility check for United States - Details by Region", "for" & Chr(32))(1), Chr(32) & Chr(45))(0)
End Sub
```

**As an UDF in the sheet**

```
Public Function GetCountry(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    GetCountry = Split(Split(rng.Text, "for" & Chr$(32))(1), Chr$(32) & Chr$(45))(0)
End Function
```

**Use in sheet:**

[image]